# Flutter-SfCalendar - Need Resources in x position and time in Y position

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar, sfcalendar

I am using sfcalendar in my mobile app in flutter for showing the appointments. It is showing the staffs(Resources) in Y position and timing(working hours) in X position.

As per client requirement I want to show the staffs(Resources) in X position and timing(working hours) in Y position. How to do that with sync fusion calendar in flutter? or would you suggest any other calendar to achieve that?

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.